# Execute without `bundle exec` via rubygems-bundler

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, bundler

I have a standard gem scaffold, and in inside the `bin` directory I have a simple executable (`bin/do_things.rb`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'my_gem'
MyGem::doThings()
```

The gem hasn't been installed via `gem install`, so running `bin/do_things.rb` without `bundle exec` fails (my `Gemfile` has the `gemspec` line in it).

Is there a simple way to have rubygems-bundler execute my script in the bundler context? Should I just modify the `$LOAD_PATH` in my executable instead?

I could create a wrapper script to execute under Bundler as well, but I'd rather leverage rubygems-bundler somehow.

Or should I just type `bundle exec`?

Comment: Can you clarify the purpose of your script? Is it something you use only in development or something that users of your gem use? In any case, I don't recommend modifying your load path directly in the executable.

Comment: When installed, the purpose of the gem executable would be to do some shell utility stuff--in my case move some files around. It'd be accessible by users after install.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try:

```
bundle exec bash -l
```

it will set you into bundler context - it's an extra shell so running `exit` will get you back to bundler less context.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for. No modifications necessary to the script. This worked for me: `bundle exec zsh -l`

Comment: Also, on OSX, I had to take out the first `bash` for it to work: `bundle exec bash -l`

Answer (score 2):

Change the file permission

```
chmod a+x bin/do_things.rb
```

and resolve bin path, ignoring symlinks

```
require "pathname"
bin_file = Pathname.new(__FILE__).realpath
```

post, add self to libpath

```
$:.unshift File.expand_path("../../lib", bin_file)
```

Answer (score 2):

Generating binstubs via `bundle install --binstubs` creates a wrapper script for all executables listed in my gemspec.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
#
# This file was generated by Bundler.
#
# The application 'do_things.rb' is installed as part of a gem, and
# this file is here to facilitate running it.
#
require 'pathname'
ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] ||= File.expand_path("../../Gemfile",
  Pathname.new(__FILE__).realpath)

require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler/setup'

load Gem.bin_path('my_gem', 'do_things.rb')
```

However, by default, the binstubs path is `bin`, which conflicts with gem's executable path, and will overwrite files in `bin`.

Running `bundle install --binstubs=SOME_DIR` and then adding `SOME_DIR` to `.gitignore` seem to be the most maintainable way.

Then, I can simple execute `SOME_DIR/do_things` or any other project-specific executable I add down the line.